# npm start fails with unexpected token in file from local dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, react-scripts

I made *first-app* with `create-react-app` where a component makes use of some [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) components, and it is working fine when started with `npm start`.

From this application I extracted that *nice-component* component in a new `nice-component` folder, with its `package.json`, the component is in a `.js` file that `export default` the component class - in Visual Studio Code I can succesfully navigate to its sources, so I would guess the setup / folder configuration is correct.

In *final-app* application, a new application still made with `create-react-app` I added *nice-component* as a local dependency (`file:../nice-component`), but when I run `npm start` I get:

```
SyntaxError: C:\...\other-package.js: Unexpected token (83:8)

  81 |       const { classes } = this.props;
  82 |       return (
> 83 |         <Grid container className={classes.root} style={{margin:30}}>
     |         ^
```

I can't figure out why that happens, it seems that local dependencies do not bring in their own (transitive) dependencies, but I successfully used a similar approach months ago in another project - where though I didnt use `react-scripts`, but set up babel, webpack, etc by myself.

I even tried adding all of material-ui dependencies in *final-app* (although I don't think I shouldn't), but yet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue Unexpected token '<' is because of missing the babel preset.

you can simply install the babel dependency using node as follows

`npm install babel-preset-react`

Thank you

Comment: Hey! That worked! Can you share a bit more of explanation? I.e. where is `npm start` failing with the component from the local dep, while working when the component is part of the current application?

Comment: I'm sorry, but with all the tests I was doing, I didn't notice that I had copied the component locally to the _ final-app_. I cleaned that up and returned using the component from the local dependency: I get the same error

Comment: I've managed to get something by following [this guide on creating a library of react components](https://medium.com/hackernoon/creating-a-library-of-react-components-using-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d182df690c6b); basically the component code must be manually / explicitly transpiled with babel to be usable in the other application.

Comment: You were close, though the issue lied in the other package (the local dependency); it's that one that needed to be babel-transpiled before being used as dependency. I was wrongly expecting `npm start` to do that.